# Historical precipitation for every place in the USA

Tags: data-request

I am here to seek historical precipitation data that displays every area in the United States, but specifically in southwest Kansas on the grassland. Here is the screenshot I am sharing.

With:
We would like to find an interactive map that can display in 7, 12, 24 or so hours, or at least a day or so in the past 30 days...

Can you suggest a website?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see daily precipitation summaries for specific observation stations on [NOAA's Climate Data Online Mapping Tool](https://gis.ncdc.noaa.gov/maps/ncei/summaries/daily). I tried to link you directly to the precipitation map for your area of interest, but that doesn't seem to be possible. Here's how to get to the data you want:

[image]

Use the rectangle select tool to see the stations in your area of interest.

[image]

You may also be interested in the Hourly/Subhourly map, which you can access through the Map Finder button  [image]on the top toolbar.

Comment: Consider also the High Plains Regional Climate Center at https://hprcc.unl.edu